# Can two mysql SELECT FOR UPDATE FROM mytable WHERE .. IN (..) deadlock?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

Can two or more instances of the following deadlock with one another?

```
START TRANSACTION
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE myid IN (list-of-ids) FOR UPDATE
:
COMMIT
```

Points to keep in mind:

- **mycolumn** is indexed
- This is mariaDB/innoDB
- There is only one table involved (`mytable`)

Example A:

```
Thread 1:

    START TRANSACTION
    SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE myid IN (100,200) FOR UPDATE
    :
    COMMIT    

Thread 2: (note that IN-list is in opposite order)

    START TRANSACTION
    SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE myid IN (200,100) FOR UPDATE
    :
    COMMIT
```

Could these threads possibly deadlock on the SELECT in mariaDB/innoDB?

Example B:

```
Thread 1:

    START TRANSACTION
    SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE myid IN (100,200) FOR UPDATE
    :
    COMMIT    

Thread 2: (note that IN-list is in same order)

    START TRANSACTION
    SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE myid IN (100,200) FOR UPDATE
    :
    COMMIT
```

Could these threads possibly deadlock on the SELECT  in mariaDB/innoDB?

**UPDATE**: A traditional way of avoiding deadlocks is to be sure to acquire locks in the same order, so that you can't have Thread 1 owning lock A and waiting on lock B while Thread 2 owns lock B and is waiting on lock A. However, I've seen several posts suggesting that even getting a single lock can't be considered atomic, because there are asynchronous processes going on in the engine that could still result in deadlock (and as a corollary to this, advising developers to always expect deadlocks and recover from them by retrying the transaction). I'm really asking whether deadlock can be eliminated by using proper coding practices in **innoDB**.)

Comment: In theory `IN (100,200)` and `IN (200,100)` is irrelevant. The DBMS can read and lock the rows in any way it wants. Therefore T1 can acquire locks that T2 will need later and T2 acquire locks that T1 will need later i.e. a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is discussing *one* example of deadlocks.  There are dozens, maybe hundreds, of ways to get a deadlock.

Sure, sorting the ids *might* prevent the `IN(100,200)` case, but what about all the rest?  Sure, go ahead and sort the ids.  And be sure to have suitable indexes.  And so on.  These might at least *diminish the frequency* of deadlocks.

Another example of a deadlock cause:  Lack of an index that leads to a table scan instead of an index lookup.  I think this can lead to locking all rows in the table, thereby both slowing things down and by having more locks, thereby begging for a deadlock.

I'll tell you what I have said many a time:  **Deadlocks happen; live with it.**  Be ready to restart the transaction from the `BEGIN`.

If you ever get a second deadlock, you should probably abort the program and spend some quality time figuring out how to speed up the entire transaction.  *That* is the best way to *minimize* deadlocks.

(OK, I'll admit that I don't know the definitive answer about `IN()`.  Long ago (ver 4.1?), I thought I had proof that sorting was beneficial.  Later I heard that MySQL sorted the `IN` list, thereby killing my theory.  Or is all this hearsay evidence?)

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you run 2 sessions concurrently, selecting the 2 data sets (myid = 100 / myid = 200) in reverse order, eg:

```
-- session #1 runs:
start transaction;
select mycolumn from mytable where myid = 100 for update;
do sleep(30);
select mycolumn from mytable where myid = 200 for update;
commit;
```

And while session #1 is sleeping:

```
-- session #2 runs:
start transaction;
select mycolumn from mytable where myid = 200 for update;
do sleep(30);
select mycolumn from mytable where myid = 100 for update;
commit;
```

Do you get a deadlock?

NOTE: (Obviously?) You can run the above test, selecting `myid=100/200` in the same order, to see what happens re: deadlocking.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64733/discussion-on-answer-by-markp-can-two-mysql-select-for-update-from-mytable-where).